# Google maps Infowindow style correction when is RTL language

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

I have this google maps marker infowindow that I would like to correct the padding when a RTL language is in place.
I tried this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {        
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    if ($('div').css('direction') == 'rtl') {
        $("div.gm-style-iw").css("padding-right", "12px");
    } 
});
```

This does not correct the padding, but if I click again on the maker It does!
Any Ideas how to fix? Is there a event when the infowindow is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right event for the infowindow. It trigger the domready event when it´s done and then I can apply my style.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {        
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    if ($('div').css('direction') == 'rtl') {           
        google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function () {
            $("div.gm-style-iw").css("padding-right", "12px");
        }); 
    }
});
```